# HTTP Referrer: Prevent spoofing

Tags: http, http-referer

I want to prevent users by spoofing referrer header to access my API services.

In other words, I want to allow API being called **only** from particular domain (i.e. *www.abcd.ef*).

Documentation states:

> The Referer request header contains the address of the previous web
>   page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed.
>   The Referer header allows servers to identify where people are
>   visiting them from and may use that data for analytics, logging, or
>   optimized caching, for example.

Is there any way I can make sure that AJAX (javascript) call comes from certain domain, even though it is possible to edit http referer header field to act like you come from *www.abcd.ef*?

Comment: Is www.abcd.ef under your control? Can you influence them, or can you query them for some piece of information?

Comment: Yes, I am admin of that domain. @ManishMaheshwari

Comment: @Lululu did you find an aswer to your question?